# how to navigate to different webpage from code behind

Tags: asp.net

I have kept url of two page in two different session and from code behind I need to navigate to that page but I am not being able to do that.I have done like this:

```
if (Session["url"]!=null)
                {
                    string url = Session["url"].ToString();
                    //HyperLink obj = new HyperLink();

                    //HyperLink.NavigateUrl = piccom.displayLink(url);
                    Response.Redirect("url");
                    //HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("url");

                }
                else if (Session["url1"] != null)
                {
                    string url1 = Session["url1"].ToString();
                    Response.Redirect("url1");

                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("You havenot select the payment method");
                }
```

I am getting error that there is no page like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `Response.Redirect(url)` insetead of `Response.Redirect("url");` remove ""

```
  if (Session["url"]!=null)
    {
     string url = Session["url"].ToString();
     Response.Redirect(url);
    }
    else if (Session["url1"] != null)
    {
        string url1 = Session["url1"].ToString();
        Response.Redirect(url1);
    }
    else{
       Response.Write("You havenot select the payment method");
    }
```

Comment: @user3247426: glad to help u,

Comment: that's correct, but there are some better solutions based on Domian Edwards presentation, http://ehsanghanbari.com/Post/125/aspnet-dont-do-that-do-this

Comment: @Ehsan: It would be much usefull for us if you answered the better solution you know, rather then posting your `blog link` bad traffic generating idea

Comment: Response.Redirect(string) calls the Response.End(), so it abort the current thread. it's not the best solution to use Response.Redirect()

Comment: @Ehsan: As per my knowledge for redirecting page i use `Response.Redirect()` and `Server.transfer()` , pls tell me how to do with `Response.end()`

Comment: it's about asp.net built in architecture, please see the presentation

Comment: @Ehsan: dude if u dont have answer/Knowledge then pls don't misguide others by commenting anything

Comment: did you see the presentation darling!!?? I won't misguide anyone, rather than that it DOES Not come in comments!! thanks